# android emulator not starting

Tags: android

My Android Emulator has stopped working. There is no error. Its just taking forever to launch. I have reinstalled eclipse indigo, Android SDK even Java se. Thats what it shows in console

```
[2012-08-02 13:05:14 - Task Reminder] Android Launch!
[2012-08-02 13:05:14 - Task Reminder] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-02 13:05:14 - Task Reminder] Performing com.android.taskreminder.TaskReminderActivity activity launch
[2012-08-02 13:05:14 - Task Reminder] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Device1'
[2012-08-02 13:05:14 - Task Reminder] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Device1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything in the Logcat console ?

Some other things you could try:

- Have you tried to delete the AVD and create a fresh one ?
- Does it happen with all versions of the Android SDK that you have ?
- Suggest to also select "Wipe User Data" and then try to restart the AVD.

Comment: There is nothing in the Logcat. I have tried to delete a device and creat a new one . Yes it happenes with all the versions of the SDK. I am new to android development, can't find "Wipe User Data" option.

Comment: ok have found the "wipe user data" option. still not working. I have to finish my work and I can't get out of this problem for past 1 week. any other suggestion?

Comment: I am not sure what is happening. I suggest as a last resort to download the Android Dev Tools and SDK again in a new directory. Remember to delete off all the old AVDs. And try with that. Sorry, but that is the best I can think of at this moment.

Comment: I downloaded ADT as well but it didn't work. Amazingly emulator works if I run it through command prompt, and after that I run the application from eclipse and select already running avd. Somehow eclipse is unable to run emulator. Atleast now my work is not blocked for past 2 weeks, but I have to rund emulator using command prompt. Have anyone got any idea after this info?

Answer (score 0):

Do adb reset in eclipse ddms devices view

```
Go to adb shell try this

    adb shell stop
    adb shell start
    restart adb by using adb kill-server and adb start-server then check adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

In AVD manager you'll want to delete your old API level and add a new API - then the Android Emulator should open.